# How can i get values from JSON using prompt?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to use json to change the background for the current user.
There are different users with different backgrounds.

I'm currently using prompt() to get the user.
The btn is the button, and the slider is the image.
Is there an easy way to get the current users background?

Sorry if its a stupid question, i am new to this.

```
let images = '{ "characters" : [' +
  '{ "name":"T" , "image":"WallP.jpg" },' +
  '{ "name":"A" , "image":"WallP2.jpg" },' +
  '{ "name":"G" , "image":"WallP3.jpg" } ]}';
  
  const query = JSON.parse(images);
  
  let element = document.getElementById("btn");
  let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let box = prompt("Enter your name:", "T");
    // slider.src = query.characters["name":"T"].image;
  });
```

Comment: so the user is expected to either type `T`, `A` or `G` (and any other input will be wrong) ?

Comment: Will this work for you? query.characters.find( c => c.name === "T" )

Comment: this is just beta :D

Comment: Not that it matters for the question, but why are you creating a string then parsing it as json? Why not just create the JSON object directly?

Comment: i dont know how to mark this as solved but it works with this:

Comment: let answer = query.characters.find(c => c.name === box);
console.log(answer["image"]);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `find` to find the background image you need:

```js
slider.src = query.characters.find(({ name }) => name === box).image
```